# check if a number exists on a csv file

Tags: php, jquery, html, csv

Ok, bear with me on this one.
I have a CSV file with approximately 1000 numbers located on a server.

The user needs to enter a number in a text field.
On submit the code needs to check if the number exists in the file.

If it does, I want to delete it from the file and present "content A" to the user.
If it does not, I want to present "content B" to the user.

I have no idea on how to approach this.
Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: where are ur efforts dude?

Comment: my efforts were all looking for a solution on google. when i could not find anything that comes even close i tried my luck here. this is not my area of expertise

Comment: What is the format of your CSV file?

Comment: convert csv to object --> search object were fieldvalue = #####, --> delete item from object ---> resave object as CSV

Answer (score 0):

How efficient does it need to be?

A very simple solution (and inefficient) could be to use `file_get_contents` to read the entire file to a string, `explode` the string (first into lines, then into fields) using your delimiters and using a for loop to scan for the matching integer.

If a match is found, remove it from the array, `implode` it to a string again and write the file again

Comment: thanks Jervelund. this is beyond my capabilities. going to leave this one :)

Answer (score 0):

How I would approach this would be;

1. How would I read and write CSV files?
2. Do I simply treat is as a String?
3. Given a String/Collection of objects, How would I find the one I need?

Me personally, I would use a combination of RegEx and Simple file reader and writer. For the effort of mapping CSV elements to Objects would be overkill for this example

Comment: thanks mike. this is beyond my capabilities. going to leave this one :)